# xcodeのコメントの予測候補を無効にしたい

Tags: xcode

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
xcode8から？コメントに対しても予測候補が表示されるようになりました。
予測候補とは、ある程度入力したら一致するメソッドの候補が表示されるあれです。

あれがxcode8あたりからコメントにも使われるようになってのか、コメントに対しても表示されます。
コメントに対しての候補は役に立ったことがないばかりか、コメント入力後にエンターで改行できないため大変不便です（エンターで候補の一番上が勝手に入力されるので候補を消すためにアローキーの→を入力しなければいけない）

これを無効化しようと設定を探したのですが、どうもメソッドの候補と同じ扱いでして、
無効にすると便利なメソッド候補も表示されなくなりました。
何か設定はあるのでしょうか？

Comment: 僕の環境ではコメントへの候補リスト表示はされていないのですが、候補リストをその度に消すには`ESC`キーを押すのが良いと思います。

Comment: 候補を消す作業が鬱陶しいので表示さえしないでほしいです…

Comment: 私の環境でもコメントへの候補リストは出てきませんが、Xcodeではなく、IMEの問題ではありませんか？

Comment: IMEの問題でしたら、環境設定のAutoSuggestとその一つ下のUse Escape key...をオンにして、候補が出ていない状態で`esc`キーを叩いてみると良いかと思います。`esc`キーで候補が出るようならSuggestの可能性が高く、今までの入力・変換がキャンセルされるならIMEのSuggestの可能性が高いと思います。ちなみに僕はATOKを使っていますが。コメント入力中に`esc`を押しても no completion というメッセージが出るだけでした。

Comment: 候補が出ていない状態でescを押すと候補が出てきました
ひらがな入力中にescを押すと入力がキャンセルされました

Comment: 候補が出ていない状態でescを押して、候補が出てくるので無視してひらがなを入力すると候補が「no completions」になります。

Comment: エスケープで閉じると表示されなくなるということでしょうか？
今表示されなくなった気がします